# Make text perpendicular to circle?

Tags: inkscape, text

Is there a way to make text perpendicular to a circle? Something like (not manifesto or I enjoy staying inspired but the other text):

[image]

I tried rotating the text block 90 degrees then putting it on path of a circle but that displayed as normal.

I've looked into text flow but the text remains horizontal as opposed to rotating around the origin.

I also know I can move the transform point, but I'm looking for a way to do this for multiple text objects or one large text block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Type one text box with one line of sample text, and rotate it 90° anti-clockwise to make it vertical.
2. Set up a circle and some guides to help you position everything, and make sure your text is placed at the 12 o'clock position
3. Click on the text box twice to show the rotations handles, then click and drag the rotation centre of the text box to the origin of the circle, using the guides you set up previously
4. Duplicate the text box using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
5. In the Transform panel, apply a Rotate transform, say about 5°
6. Repeat steps 4 to 5 until you have made all the rotated text boxes
7. Type the text you want in each text box.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 3):

They are easy to make as separate rotated text blocks

Make a group which contains a horizontal line and a text block. The line is used only as a reference for "how big circle I was going to do"

[image]

Move the rotation center of the group to the left end of the line. Set point snaps and snap to the rotation center ON to be able to place the rotation center exactly.

Duplicate the group. Use Object > Transform > Rotate to rotate the certain wanted angle which is calculated beforehand. Remember that full turn around the circle is 360 degrees. I rotated 6 degrees.

Duplicate (=Ctrl+D) the rotated copy and apply the rotate dialog again to get more text lines

[image]

You can select the text blocks in the Objects panel or by double clicking and change the texts. Finally remove the lines or close them in the objects panel. Save at least one to keep the centerpoint and radius in safe.

BTW. You may want to align the line and the text to the same horizontal midline before making a group. This is useful if you are going to get a good fit when there's many different text sizes and maybe other objects too and everyone must seem to point the came circle center.

[image]

An experienced Inkscape user probably wouldn't make every new line as Duplicate+Rotate, he would create a full 360 degrees by applying Edit > Clone > Create Tiled Clones:

[image]

There's a trick: Shift Y must be set to -100% to prevent vertical moving downwards.

[image]

Another thing to remember is to make the clones independent to be able to change texts (Edit > Clone > Unlink Clones)

There's also the original left, so delete one at the original position.

The lines can be selected all by selecting one (after Ungrouping) and then applying Edit > Select Same > Stroke Color.